# Can you display matplotlib objects or figures in tkinter without using the plot() command?

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to embed a already made matplotlib figure and want to embed that figure in my tkinter window without a separate pop up window.
can you please help if there is a way to display matplotlib objects in tkinter **without using** the `plot()` command?

any help would be highly appreciated
thanks..

Comment: See [Matplotlib's official sample](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html) on embedding in Tk.

Comment: Yes I did go thorugh it but I couldn't find a method to embed the figure without the plot command

Maybe I am missing something elsewhere?